# Why is css transform-origin cutting space from top and left?

Tags: css

I have an svg container inside a div container,

```
.map-container {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  img {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  .svg-container {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
  }
}
```

Inside my Vue component template I'm zooming in using css transform: scale().

```
<div class="map-container" :style="{ transform: `scale(${store.zoomLevel})` }">
```

The problem is that if transform-origin in not set to top left (it's not there or has 50% 50% or center values), then when zooming, the left and top part are cut off and you cant' scroll to them like you can down or right. Can I fix it still having transform-origin centering the image on zoom?